# Can not receive any packages when using TCP socket

Tags: c++, tcp, tcpdump

I wrote a Tcp socket for receiving TCP packages in C++, my code as following:

```
class ReceiverTcp{
    private:
        struct sockaddr_in recv_addr;
        char recv_pack[64*10 + 20];
        int lost_pack_num;
        int max_wait_time;
        fd_set fds;
        int sockId;

    public:
        ReceiverTcp();
        ~ReceiverTcp();
        void CreateSocket();
        void RecvPacket();
        int ResolvePakcet();    
};
ReceiverTcp::ReceiverTcp(){
}
ReceiverTcp::~ReceiverTcp() {
}
void ReceiverTcp::CreateSocket(){
    this->sockId = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(this->sockId == -1){
        printf("Create socket error!!! \n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = 4;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    setsockopt(this->sockId, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char*)&tv, sizeof tv);

    FD_ZERO(&this->fds);
    FD_SET(this->sockId, &this->fds);

    struct sockaddr_in r_addr;
    bzero(&r_addr, sizeof(r_addr));
    r_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    r_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.2.90");
    r_addr.sin_port = htons(9990);
};

void ReceiverTcp::RecvPacket(){
    int recv_size, fromlen;
    fromlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr);

    int maxfd = this->sockId + 1;
    struct timeval timeout;
    timeout.tv_sec = this->max_wait_time;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    int n = select(maxfd, NULL, &this->fds, NULL, &timeout);

    switch(n) {
        case -1:
            fprintf(stderr, "Select error:%s \n\a", strerror(errno));
            printf("SELECT -1 ERROR\n");
        case 0:
            printf("SELECT 0 TIMEOUT!\n");
            lost_pack_num++;
            break;
        default:
            if(FD_ISSET(this->sockId, &fds)) {
                memset(recv_pack, 0, sizeof(recv_pack));
                recv_size = recvfrom(this->sockId, recv_pack, sizeof(recv_pack), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&recv_addr, (socklen_t *)&fromlen);
                if(recv_size < 0) {
                    cout<<"receive size less than 0\n";
                } else{
                    ResolvePakcet();
                }
            }else{
                cout<<"receive socket error!"<<endl;
            }
     }
}

int ReceiverTcp::ResolvePakcet() {
    ip_hdr *ip;
    u_int ip_len = sizeof(struct ip_hdr);
    ip = (ip_hdr*) recv_pack;
    if (ip->protocol == 1) {
        cout<<"ICMP\n";
    }else if(ip->protocol==6){
        cout<<"TCP \n";
    }else{
        cout<<"Other Protocol!"<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I ran CreateSocket and RecvPacket functions, I could not get any data from recvfrom() function. But I did can find the input packages from TCPDump command, so my code should be something wrong. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: look for last error and this stuff

Comment: This is just an incomplete code dump. While it contains debug information you don't show any debug output from actually using the code in a larger program which means there are no actual information about what is happening in the code. Also note that tcpdump sniffs data before they pass through the firewall, i.e. it might well be that the firewall is blocking the traffic. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Jack You are using a TCP socket, so you should be using `recv()` instead of `recvfrom()`. But more importantly, `select()` *modifies* the `fd_set`s it is given, so once `select()` reports a timeout, `this->fds` has lost the socket, and you never reset `this->fds` for future calls to `select()`. There is no good reason to have `fds` as a member of the `ReceiverTcp` class to begin with, it should be a local variable inside of `RecvPacket()` instead. Also, where is the call to `connect()` before `RecvPacket()`?